# Union of elements in a sigma algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

For a sigma algebra $\sigma$, it is true that if $A \in \sigma$ and $B \in \sigma$, then $A \cup B \in \sigma$. My question is, for another $C = A' \cup B'$ where $C \in \sigma$; are $A'$ and $B'$ also part of the sigma algebra? In other words, is it true that:

$C \in \sigma \Rightarrow A' \in \sigma, B' \in \sigma$

Comment: Yes, you can prove that sigma algebras are closed under union, intersection, complementation, and difference despite some of those not being included in the definition.  As for the question of if a set is an element of a sigma algebra and the set can be expressed as the union of a particular pair of smaller sets whether those smaller sets must be elements, no that need not be the case.  Consider the trivial sigma algebra $\{\emptyset, X\}$ where $X$ has at least two elements as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False!

Let $X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Then $M = \{\emptyset, \{2,3\},\{1,4,5\},X\}$ is a sigma algebra over $X$

Then $\{2,3\} \in M$ but $\{3\},\{2\} \notin M$

Comment: What if $M = \sigma(X)$, the sigma field generated by X (The smallest sigma field containing all the elements of X)?. Would it be true?

Comment: $\sigma(X) = \{\emptyset,X\}$ , then X = {1} $\cup$ {2,3,4,5} 

But {1} $\notin \sigma(X)$

Answer (score 1):

Take $B'$ to be any nonmeasurable set. Take $A'$ to be its complement (also nonmeasurable). Then $A'\cup B'=X$, your entire space which is measurable.